# Generating forms with foreach loop inside another form

Tags: php, html, forms, foreach

I want to generate 2 `forms` inside a `parent form` with `foreach loop`. It's weird to see that the `first form` isn't generating and the `parent form` is ending before the child form(s) is generating. Why is it so?

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <?php
        $array = [1,2];
        foreach ($array as $arr) {
            echo '<form action="" id="'.$arr.'" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="hello">
                 </form>';
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

It should look like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   <form action="" id="1" method="POST">
      <input type="text" placeholder="hello">   
   </form>
   <form action="" id="2" method="POST">
      <input type="text" placeholder="hello">   
   </form>
</form>
```

It's looking like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   <input type="text" placeholder="hello">   
</form>
<form action="" id="2" method="POST">
   <input type="text" placeholder="hello">   
</form>
```

Comment: Your code works as it  should work - https://eval.in/600035

Comment: Where are you checking the output? in a browser or in a terminal or some other output format - where  you can get a look at the code as its generated by PHP?

Comment: checking it in browser. Strange but it's giving me the weird output.

Comment: You shouldn't nest forms. According to [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) form contains "Flow content, but with no form element descendants.".

Comment: @Wazelin Maybe you are right. But in my current situation, I have to.

Comment: copy-paste and Run your code in stand alone php file on localhost. it works as expected.

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND It does. The source code shows what is expected.  But did you inspect on the first input tag?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your short syntax array. Try replacing `$array = [1,2];` by  `$array = array(1,2);`

Input closing slash. `<input type="text" placeholder="hello">` by `<input type="text" placeholder="hello"/>`

OR

```
   $childForm = '';
   <?php
        $array = array(1,2);
        foreach ($array as $arr) {
            $childForm .= '<form action="" id="'.$arr.'" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="hello"/>
                 </form>';
        }
   ?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <?php echo $childForm; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: It's the same thing. On viewing the page source, you will see everything is fine. But tell me what you see when you inspect on the first input tag.